# Find an Object in a List of Object based on one of its member's attribute(s)

Tags: java, list

Let's say I have an object called `House`, which contains a `List<Room>`:

```
public class House {

private List<Room> roomsList;

public House(List<Room> rooms) {
    roomsList = rooms;
}

/*Getter and Setter*/
...
```

And for Room, just an attribute `color` with its value respresented by an `int`:

```
public calss Room {

private int color;

public Room(int c) {
    color = c;
}

/*Getter and Setter*/
...
```

Now, Using Java 8, and given an object `House` with a `List<Room>` already set, I know how to find an object `Room` inside my `House` based on a value of `color`, for example :

```
Room myRoom = house.getRooms.stream().filter(r -> r.getColor() == color).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

What I would like to be able to do is, given a `List<House>` and a value of `int c`, to find a or several `House` with a `Room` whose attribute `color` is equal to `c`

Just to be clear, for my use case :

- the `List<House>` is neither null or empty;
- every `House` has a `List<Room>` which is neither null or empty;
- every `Room` has its attribute `color` set;
- every `Room` inside a `House` has a unique color
- there is most likely (but not necessarily) only 1 `House` with a `Room` of the given `color`

I could do something like this :

```
List<House> houseList = /*a given list of houses*/
int c = 4;

House myHouse = null;

for (House house : houseList) {
    List<Room> rooms = house.getRooms();
    Room roomOfRightColor = house.getRooms.stream().filter(r -> r.getColor() == color).findFirst().orElse(null);
    if (room != null) {
        myHouse = house;
        break;
    }

if (myHouse == null) {
/*Handle null*/
}

return myHouse;
```

But maybe there is a smarter and/or more direct way of doing this?

Comment: @MartinvanWingerden it is a similar problem I'll give you that, and the solution you provided is basically the same kind as the answers to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can imagine similar questions have been asked before, the trick is here to next filter operations:

```
private static Optional<House> test() {
    List<House> houseList = Arrays.asList(
            new House(new Room(1), new Room(3)),
            new House(new Room(5))
    );
    int color = 5;

    return houseList.stream()
            .filter(h -> h.getRooms()
                    .stream()
                    .anyMatch(r -> r.getColor() == color))
            .findFirst();
}
```

So inside the filter you have a second match which checks the inner-list. I did change it to return an optional instead of null's but feel free to apply what works for you.

Comment: Ok, so you can "chain" the stream operations? I didn't know that. Thank you :)